# Ruby Variable replacement inside another Variable

Tags: ruby, variables

I have a ruby variable created from a complex code , But I am unable to replace the variable declared inside my main variable . 
Here is an example , it may be simple but I could not able to change main variable declaration procedure.

```
irb(main):065:0> p msg
"My name is \#{name}"
irb(main):066:0> puts name
Foo
irb(main):067:0> puts msg
My name is #{name}
irb(main):068:0> puts "#{msg}"
My name is #{name}
```

I want an output like "My name is Foo" ; That needs to be achieved considering I can't control content format of variable 'msg'

Comment: Is `msg` a simple String, or is it a custom class?

Comment: Consider 'msg' is a simple variable , but It passed from a different procedure , So I cant change the declaration format .

Comment: I understand that you cannot control `msg`. That means you cannot use string interpolation at all. But is there any specification on how `msg` will look like? Like it contains always `\#{name}`? Or is it possible that `msg` might have a totally different format (like correct string interpolation) or different variables names (like `fullname`)?

Answer (score 2):

You could build your own String class with a substitution at runtime.

```
class StringInterpollator < String
  def replace(bind)
    gsub(/\\*#\{(\w+)\}/) do |m|
      eval($1, bind)
    end
  end
end

msg = 'My name is \#{name}'
name = "Foo"

StringInterpollator.new(msg).replace binding #My name is Foo
```

EDIT: here a version that accepts both local variables as instance variables

```
class StringInterpollator < String
  def replace(bind)
    gsub(/\\*#\{?([\w@]+)\}?/){ |m| eval($1, bind)}
  end
end
```

Comment: The backslash isn't in the string in the question. See the `puts msg` output.

Comment: Hi, If I pass the instance variable like #{@name}, it's not working. Should I send something else instead of binding in this case?

Comment: puts wil not show the \, p does.

Instance variables behave differently, eg they don't need the curly brackets, published a version that handles them both

Answer (score 0):

One simple approach is to use string substitution with the `sub` method like this

```
name = "Foo"
msg.sub('#{name}', name) # => "My name is Foo"
```

However, this assumes that `msg` always contains the text `\#{name}`